# 0-1 knapsack with non-linear objective function

Tags: optimization, combinatorial-optimization, knapsack

There's efficient algorithms for solving the 0-1 knapsack problems when the objective function is just a sum of profits. I am dealing with the following problem with non-linear objective function:

$$\max_{S \subseteq N}  \frac{\left( \sum_{k\in S} a_k \right) \cdot \left(\sum_{k\in S} b_k \right)}{1 + \sum_{k\in S} b_k}\;\;\; \text{subject to}\;\;\; \sum_{k\in S} w_k \leq C,$$

where $a_i, b_i, w_i \geq 0 \;\; \forall \;\; i \in N. $

I can transform this problem into the equivalent MILP formulation using CC transformation, but it cannot be solved in polynomial time if $N$ is large. Is there any technique or developed algorithm to solve this in polynomial time?

Comment: Would you see [this](http://or.dei.unibo.it/library/non-linear-knapsack-problem) link? I hope it helps.

Comment: Could you please let me know how to use this? I see some files, but no algorithms.

Comment: It is unclear to me what are your variables, and what are your constants ? Are all the coefficients constant, and the binary variables not written ?

Comment: Decision variable is $S$, the set. Each element $i \in N = \{1, 2, ..., n\}$ is represented by the triplet $(a_i, b_i, w_i)$. This is similar to 0-1 knapsack problem, but the objective function has non-linear structure.

Comment: This can be solved via dynamic programming

Comment: @Steven01123581321 I am not sure about the dynamic programming. You would have to be able to express the cost function  $\frac{A_jB_j}{1+B_j}$ in terms of $\frac{A_{j-1}B_{j-1}}{1+B_{j-1}} + ...$. This is not straightforward.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think you can solve this as a bi-objective knapsack problem as there is an efficient solution to the knapsack problem with objectives $(\max \sum_{k\in S} a_k,\max \sum_{k\in S} b_k) $ that maximizes the original objective function. Solving a bi-knapsack problem is however not necessarily a trivial task.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even though knapsack problems are relatively easy to solve in practice, there does not exist a polynomial-time algorithm to solve even the standard knapsack problem, unless $\mathcal{P}=\mathcal{NP}$. The knapsack problem can be solved in *pseudo-polynomial* time $\mathcal{O}(nC)$. Even when the input length (=number of digits describing the problem) is small, the actual number $C$ may be large (e.g., I only need six digits to write the number 999,999), which is why the complexity is not polynomial.

Let $n$ be the number of items, and let $B = \sum_{k\in N} b_k$. Then I think you can solve your problem in pseudo-polynomial time $\mathcal{O}(nCB^2)$ as follows:

1. Add the constraint $\sum_{k \in S} b_k = D$ for some $D \in \{0,\dots,B\}$.
2. The factor $\frac{\sum_{k\in S} b_k }{1 + \sum_{k\in S} b_k}$ is now a constant and can be removed from the objective. What remains is a multidimensional knapsack problem in dimension two, with one inequality and one equality constraint.
3. Solve the problem with dynamic programming. Let $f_D(k,c,d)$ be the best objective value obtainable after processing the first $k$ items, with a total weight less than or equal to $c$ and for which the current sum of the $b_k$ weights is exactly $d$. To calculate the value of $f_D(k,c,d)$ you pick the best of two options

   1. Not selecting item $k$, which gives you objective $f_D(k-1,c,d)$.
   2. Or selecting item $k$, which gives you objective $f_D(k-1,c-w_k,d-b_k)$.
4. Record the optimal solution for $D$, given by $f_D(n, C, D)$.
5. Repeat 1-4 for all possible values of $D$ and compare the solutions to select the best one.

For a given $D$, the dynamic program calculates $\mathcal{O}(nCB)$ values, each in constant time. Repeating this for all $D\in \{0,\dots,B\}$ and comparing the outcomes puts the complexity in $\mathcal{O}(nCB^2)$.

It should be noted that the multi-dimensional knapsack problem is significantly more difficult than the standard knapsack problem. For example, knapsack allows for a FPTAS, while the multi-dimensional knapsack does not, even in dimension two. Dynamic programming is not necessarily the best approach in practice. [This Knapsack Problems book](http://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-24777-7) discusses both dynamic programming and other approaches in detail. Finally, a direct method for non-linear knapsack may be better than fixing $D$ and solving the remainder, as I showed here.